# Angular4 default load boostrap library?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, angular

I new a angular4 project and write the code in app.component.html

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-1">.col-md-1</div>
    <div class="col-md-1">.col-md-1</div>
    <div class="col-md-1">.col-md-1</div>
    <div class="col-md-1">.col-md-1</div>
    <div class="col-md-1">.col-md-1</div>
    <div class="col-md-1">.col-md-1</div>
    <div class="col-md-1">.col-md-1</div>
    <div class="col-md-1">.col-md-1</div>
    <div class="col-md-1">.col-md-1</div>
    <div class="col-md-1">.col-md-1</div>
    <div class="col-md-1">.col-md-1</div>
    <div class="col-md-1">.col-md-1</div>
  </div>    
</div>
```

But It no work

I look the course seems like angular4 default loading bootstrap lib by `bootstrap: [AppComponent]` 
in app.module.ts, but it didn't work for me, when I add

```
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

in index.html, then it work, why?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are confusing the framework name with the startup process. The Angular bootstrap is just defining the entry point.

Angular 4 doesn't automatically supports bootstrap UI framework. By importing the css, you will get basic static styling.

To make dynamic components to work, try [ng-bootstrap](https://github.com/ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap) or [ng2-bootstrap](http://valor-software.com/ng2-bootstrap/).

Comment: I use `npm install --save bootstrap` and add `"../node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css"` in angular-cli.json and it work, you solve my confuse, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

bootstrap(angular property): [AppComponent], is define application initial component. once you run your application on server then "AppComponent" will be call and will be display on screen.

but you are taking about bootstrap framework, for that you have to install the bootstrap in your project using following command.

```
npm install --save bootstrap
```

*NOTE* After run this command make sure bootstrap .min file should be add in you angular-cli.json file, if it's not added you can add manually

```
"styles": [
        "../node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css",
        "styles.css"
      ]
```